# Put folders in an array c#

Tags: c#

How do I build a console program that will read folders and files from a root folder and be able to output each folder name and the filenames.
So my path would be,
C:\base\dirA\dirB\dirC\filename.txt.

I want to output dir-A, dir-B, dir_C and filename.txt.
I want to avoid using \ as a delimiter or picking out the pattern using regex.
Can you get the folder list into an array?

Comment: Read the documentation of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: Please format your question in a more understandable format as I can't really understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Take a look at `FileSystem` methods like [GetDirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getdirectoryinfo?view=net-7.0), [GetFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getfileinfo?view=net-7.0), use it recursively. Stack overflow is not code writing service, try something by yourself and then ask for help if you get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterative approach with `while` loop

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\base\dirA\dirB\dirC\filename.txt");
Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = fi.Directory;
while (di.Name != di.Root.Name)
{
    Console.WriteLine(di.Name);
    di = di.Parent;
}
```